# Lightroom 3.5 load forever when I click on import

Tags: import, osx-leopard, lightroom

I use lightroom 3.5 on a MacOS 10.6, until now everything was fine.
Until recently : If I click on import It will load forever, If I force to quit the application, I can't restart it until I shutdown and restart my Imac.
I try to create a new catalog, delete the .plist preference file and of course to reinstall the software with no changes
Any ideas ?

Comment: In deed I found more informations without solving my problem :
It seems to crash only when I click on "Import Photos", I have the colorwheel (loading) which turns forever. If I check my system Console I have the following error from LightRoom 3: "Agshutdown duplicate listeners registered for shutdown notification key : ImportThumbnailServer" Hope it gives a clue to some of you

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue : I read on many forums that it may be an issue with the external hard drive or compact flash readers (usb devices...) That's why I ejected them : 
But it was not sufficient to solve the issue !
You need to remove physically all devices plugged to your usb ports except mouse and keyboard.
You restart your computer and lightroom.
Then all comes back to normal.
And you can plug back your external hard drive